pm2 on NestJS application throws mongoose connection error
I'm trying to deploy my NestJS app on Ubuntu with pm2 by running this command: pm2 start dist/main.js --name "myapp" --watch. But when I check out the logs it throws this error:
0|myapp  | PoolClosedError [MongoPoolClosedError]: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection pool
0|myapp  |     at ConnectionPool.processWaitQueue (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection_pool.ts:715:37)
0|myapp  |     at ConnectionPool.close (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection_pool.ts:472:10)
0|myapp  |     at Server.destroy (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/server.ts:264:17)
0|myapp  |     at destroyServer (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:773:10)
0|myapp  |     at node:internal/util:364:7
0|myapp  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
0|myapp  |     at destroyServer (node:internal/util:350:12)
0|myapp  |     at /home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:506:38
0|myapp  |     at Function.from (<anonymous>)
0|myapp  |     at Topology.close (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:505:36) {
0|myapp  |   address: 'localhost:27017',
0|myapp  |   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
0|myapp  | }

I checked out by running node dist/main.js, everything works perfect. I checked out src/config/config.service.ts:
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigurationService {
  private readonly _connectionString: string = 
    this._configService.get<string>('DB_URI') || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp';
  // port
  private readonly _port: number = this._configService.get<number>('API_PORT') || 3030;

  get connectionString(): string {
    return this._connectionString;
  }
  
  constructor(private readonly _configService: ConfigService) {
    this._connectionString = this._getConnectionStringFromEnvFile();
  }

  private _getConnectionStringFromEnvFile(): string {
    const connectionString = this._configService.get<string>('DB_URI') || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp';
    if (!connectionString) {
      throw new Error('No connection string has been provided in the .env file.');
    }

    return connectionString;
  }
}

I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1, nothing changed. I checked out if the mongo is running, it's good.
Why is node dist/main.js works perfect but can not start application by pm2 start dist/main.js --name "myapp" --watch?

The pool can be closed if you attempted to use it before it before connection was established, or after it was closed due to some errors. Check mongodb server logs for errors and timestamps of when the client connected/disconnected
